# vim not deleting characters in xterm

Tags: vim, gnu-screen, xterm

I have recently reinstalled my gentoo system and am now experiencing a strange problem in vim in an xterm:
If I exit the edit mode the "-- INSERT --" still is visible, though the edit mode is not active. Also, if I scroll through text longer lines are still shown throughout the window. I think it is a mistake in the clearing of characters or in some font configuration.

However, if I start a gnu screen session and use vim, everything is working fine.

Any hints of how to get my vim working properly in xterm without screen?

Is my problem well enough described to be understandable? If not I could try to add screenshots...

Thanks in advance.
jesterchen

Comment: Check your TERM variable. it should be set to `xterm`.

Comment: % echo $TERM ->
xterm
It is. In screen it is 'screen'. If I set TERM=screen and start vim, then everything is working fine. If I set TERM=bla, everything is working properly, too. So why not with TERM=xterm? There is nothing with *term in .vimrc, I completely moved my ~/.vim/ away - still no luck.

Comment: Oh my. Thanks for your hint - so I just got onto the error: I had `set encoding=utf8`, which lead to these problems. By disabling them in my .vimrc everything works fine now. Even though I do not understand, why it did not work with utf8. That's another question to be solved. :)